# What and How to install Ethernet adapter drivers

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, ethernet

I'm currently trying to set a computer with Ubuntu Server (version: 16.04.3).

I believe the drivers for the wireless adapter are installed, but I need the `iwconfig` utility/command to configure it. But in order to get `iwconfig`, I need an internet connection.

I've decided to temporarily enable ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on the Ethernet port of my Windows 7 computer, but now I'm having trouble getting an internet connection over the Ethernet connection (between the Windows computer and the Ubuntu Server computer).

Here's the output for `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
  description: Ethernet controller
  product: Qualcomm Atheros
  vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
  version: 10
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:ef100000-ef13ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
*-network DISABLED
  description: Wireless interface
  product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
  logical name: wlp8s0
  version: 00
  serial: 7c:8b:ca:0a:03:34
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ee driverversion=4.4.0-87-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  resources: irq:132 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef000000-ef003fff
```

From some digging online, the `UNCLAIMED` status leads me to believe that a driver is not installed for or not associated with the Ethernet adapter. Am I correct?

How do I figure out which driver is needed?
How do I acquire that driver (if it's not already installed)?
How do I set up / associate the driver with my device?

Here's the output for `sudo lspci -nn | grep eth`:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
```

The output for `sudo modprobe -v alx`:

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mdio.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
```

The output for `sudo ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127:0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 7c:8b:ca:0a:03:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Hardware specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu Server (version: 16.04.3)
Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-H270-Gaming 3 (rev. 1.0) LGA 1151 Intel H270
CPU: Intel Core i5 6400T
RAM: Corsair Value Select 4GB Unbuffered CL15
SSD: Kingston Digital 120GB SSDNow V300 (SV300S37A/120G)
HDD: WD Blue 1TB (WD10EZEX) | Seagate 1TB (ST1000DM003)
Wi-Fi Adapter: TP-Link N300 (TL-WN881ND)
PSU: EVGA 450 (220-B3-0450-V1)
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro How will I run `apt-get` without an internet connection? How can I access the package sources without an internet connection?

Comment: @GAD3R The output of `sudo modprobe -v alx` was:
    `insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mdio.ko`
    `insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko`

Comment: I've added some stuff to the original post.
Should I move this post to the Ubuntu stack exchange site, or is it okay to have it here?

Comment: @MaxJacob it's completely up to you. This is on topic both here and on [ubuntu.se], so it can stay here or I can move it, as you wish. In the meantime, could you [edit] your question and explain your hardware? Is Ubuntu running on a physical machine or a VM? It is very unlikely that you would need to install something for ethernet. Does `sudo modprobe e1000e` make any difference to the `lshw` output?

Comment: @terdon Ubuntu is running on a physical machine. I've listed out the specs in an edit to the post.
`sudo modprobe e1000e` did not make a difference in the `lshw` output.

Answer (score 4):

Try running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

That will install a "hardware enablement" (HWE) kernel, which is a newer version with updated drivers that will probably work better on your system. There's more info about HWE here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

A sufficient version of that should be available from your original installation media. If it isn't, then you'll probably need to "sneakernet" the files over by copying to a USB stick, or find a USB WiFi adapter that is supported by kernel version 4.4.0, and use that to download the material you need.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but the information might help other people.

So I decided to re-install Ubuntu Server. I also decided to remove the Wireless Network Adapter for the time being - just to reduce the number of variables.
When the installation screen came up, I decided to select *Install Ubuntu Server with the HWE Kernel* - instead of *Install Ubuntu Server*. Once the installation process completed, everything seemed to work fine.

Here's the output for `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: Qualcomm Atheros
     vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
     logical name: enp5s0
     version: 10
     serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:19 memory:ef000000-ef03ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

The outputs for `sudo lspci -nn | grep eth`, and `sudo modprobe -v alx` were empty.

Here's the output for `sudo ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    inet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX brd XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm going to re-install Ubuntu Server again (without HWE), just to see if that still causes the problem.

**UPDATE**

I installed Ubuntu Server again - this time without the HWE kernel.

The results are the same.

Here's the output for `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
  description: Ethernet controller
  product: Qualcomm Atheros
  vendor: QUalcomm Atheros
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
  version: 10
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:ef000000-ef03ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

The output for `sudo lspci -nn | grep eth` was mepty.

Here's the output for `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a2af
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a2ba
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a282
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2e9 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2eb (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a292 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a293 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a294 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a295 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a296 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a297 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a298 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c4
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a2a3
01:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 71)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)
```

Here's the output for `sudo modprobe -v alx`:

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mdio.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
```

Here's the output for `sudo ip a`:

```
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preffered_lft forever
```

If anyone has any input, feel free to chip in.